# Create custom button class to set style in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-button, material-components-android

I want to create a custom button class so that I don't need to always add styles in xml. I miss to add styles in xml sometimes and is created as a bug. By using Custom class, I want to remove this dependency of adding styles every time from `styles.xml`.

I want to use this approach for all textviews and editText but I am unable to find how to do this. Please suggest approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly what you are looking for.
Use the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and just define in your app theme the **`materialButtonStyle`** attribute with your favorite style.
It will define the style for the buttons globally in the app.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
   ...
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButton" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
  ...
</style>
```

Instead if you are still using an AppCompat Theme you can use the **`buttonStyle`** attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.*"/>
   ...
   <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button</item>
</style>
```